# Why isn't it possible to overload the subscript operator (operator[]) as a friend function?

Tags: c++, function, friend-function

Why we cannot overload subscript operator using friend function

Comment: Please explain, what is `operator[]` as a free function.

Comment: It's a requirement that the subscript [operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) is a member function, because you can't have a subscript without an object.

Comment: Quick answer - because the standard says so.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You literally have `[]` before objects: this comes from c-style arrays, e.g., `int[]`. In that case, it's a built-in. There's no actual issue with designing a C++-like language where `operator[]` is implementable as a free function; but C++ committee never decided to go that way.

Comment: @lorro  `int[]` is a *type* (an incomplete type), not a subscript expression.

Answer (score 0):

Not all operators can be overloaded. For those that can be overloaded there are rules whether they can be non-members or not. For details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators.

The operators that can be overloaded only as members are `=`,`()`,`[]` and `->`.

Comment: So u wish to say that subscript operator [ ] cannot be overloaded as friend? Right ?

Comment: @AkhilPrasad it cannot be overloaded as non-member / free function (so that free function can also not be a friend)

Answer (score 0):

Let's add overloading to a language that is derived from C. Did you know that the built-in operator is symmetric? For raw arrays it's always true that `a[i] == i[a]`. It's an emergent property that may be cute, but hardly conducive for great code.

So, wouldn't it be a good idea to limit our overloading to only have our "container object" on the left? Many will say yes. And it is also true that the left-hand side of an expression is always taken as `this` for member lookup.

Now if we only want to allow the object on the lhs, the choice is easy: only allow defining the operator as a member. For a similar reason `operator=` is a member-only operator too, because the object being assigned *to* only makes sense (to the language designer) on the left.

Comment: Correct me if I’m mistaken, but doesn’t `operator ->*` also have this property, but is allowed to be overloaded as a free function? It makes sense given the special nature of `operator =` that it should be a member, but I don’t see any intrinsic reason why `operator []` couldn’t have been defined as a free function or as a friend.

Comment: @templatetypedef - There's hardly an intrinsic reason for anything, `operator=` could be a free function too if someone wanted to design a language where it may be one. Overload resolution would work just the same. The only problem is if someone decided to be cute and overload it in a way that `5 = a` assigns to `a`. It's idiosyncratic and weird, but hardly a violation of some natural law. `5[a]` is cut from the same cloth, though arguably people seem to be far more accepting of it. Bjarne had a right to consider it not a good idea in overloading, and to force it to be a member.

Comment: Gotcha. Though I could imagine some weirdness if `operator=` was free function and the compiler had to defer figuring out whether to autogenerate it. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef - All to true. Gotta love a language designed with so many opposing forces in play :)